# How to apply a zipped patch?

Tags: linux, patch

I am wondering, what is the problem here?

This is the linux patch for 2.6.38. I have renamed it. This patch is gz.Thus, I am using zcat.
Here is what I see?

```
[joshis1@shreyas linux-2.6-lttng]$ zcat patch-2.6.38.2-lttng-0.248.tar.gz
```

| patch -p1

```
can't find file to patch at input line 15
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|patch-2.6.38.2-lttng-0.248/0000755000175000017500000000000011545246117014542 5ustar  compudjcompudjpatch-2.6.38.2-lttng-0.248/omap-move-resync-timer-to-cpufreq-event.patch0000644000175000017500000001631311545246117025310 0ustar  compudjcompudjomap move resync timer to cpufreq event
|
|Remove a periodic timer to save energy.
|
|Signed-off-by: Mathieu Desnoyers <mathieu.desnoyers@polymtl.ca>
|---
| arch/arm/mach-omap2/include/mach/trace-clock.h |    2 
| arch/arm/mach-omap2/trace-clock.c              |  110 +++++++++++++++----------
| 2 files changed, 68 insertions(+), 44 deletions(-)
|
|Index: linux-2.6-lttng/arch/arm/mach-omap2/include/mach/trace-clock.h
|===================================================================
|--- linux-2.6-lttng.orig/arch/arm/mach-omap2/include/mach/trace-clock.h
|+++ linux-2.6-lttng/arch/arm/mach-omap2/include/mach/trace-clock.h
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Comment: This question might get better answers over at [unix.se] rather than here.

Comment: The file you're looking at is a gzipped tar file containing patches, not a patch file. Extract it and apply the patches you find inside.

Comment: There are 50 files inside, and I cannot apply each file manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

duskwuff is correct – you’ve encountered a gzipped tarball of patches.  You should extract them all to a temporary folder; you can use your shell to apply each of them – e.g.,

```
for p in /path/to/extracted/patches/*; do patch -p1 $p; done
```